# Can we develop LiDAR apps using ARKit with SceneKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, lidar

I have read on many forums that if we want to develop a LiDAR application, we need to use `RealityKit`, instead of `SceneKit`. I am in the middle of development of [Apple LiDAR Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene?language=objc). But instead of using RealityKit, I used SceneKit. But now I got a problem since SceneKit doesn't offer `sceneUnderstanding` feature to render graphics. So I want to know basically:

- 1. Can't we develop LiDAR applications using ARKit with SceneKit?
- 2. Can we achieve `sceneUnderstanding` feature using SceneKit?
- 3. Can we develop LiDAR apps without using `sceneUnderstanding`?

Really appreciate your answers and comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scene understanding with any renderer. But only `RealityKit` comes with integration for this feature.

The `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` comes with a [`sceneReconstruction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/3521376-scenereconstruction) flag that can be enabled.
Then, `ARKit` creates [`ARMeshAnchor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armeshanchor) instances for you in the [`ARSessionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate) and [`ARSCNViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate) methods.

However, because `SceneKit` does not come with an out-of-the box support for these features you would have to build a visualization or physics interaction yourself based on the `ARMeshAncor` properties.